# Base zero-dimensional spaces

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, cardinal-characteristics

> **Definition.** A zero-dimensional topological space $X$ is called *base zero-dimensional* if for any base $\mathcal B$ of the topology that consists of closed-and-open sets in $X$, any open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ has a disjoint refinement $\mathcal V\subset\mathcal B$.

It can be shown that

(1) each countable regular space is base zero-dimensional;

(2) the Cantor set is not base zero-dimensional.

Let $\mathfrak z$ be the smallest cardinality $|Z|$ of a subset $Z\subset\mathbb R$, which is not base zero-dimensional. It follows that $\aleph_1\le\mathfrak z\le\mathfrak c$. So, $\mathfrak z$ is a typical small uncountable cardinal.

> **Problem 1.** Is $\mathfrak z$ equal to some known small uncountable cardinal? Is $\mathfrak z=\mathfrak c$ under MA or PFA?

---

**Edit 1 (written following a suggestion of @user64494):** I found a (relatively) simple solution to my original question (about the base zero-dimensionality of the Cantor set) and then edited my post asking the next natural question in this context (about the base zero-dimensionality of uncountable sets of the real line).

By the way, a base $\mathcal B$ witnessing that the Cantor cube $2^\omega$ is not base zero-dimensional consists of the sets 
$$B_s:=\{x\in 2^\omega:x{\restriction}n=s\mbox{ and }(x(n)\ne s(n)\Rightarrow x(n{+}1)=0)\}$$where $n:=\{0,\dots,n-1\}\in\omega$ and $s\in 2^{n+1}=\{0,1\}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @YCor, $[0,1]^{\omega}$ is usually called the Hilbert cube.

Comment: ah OK. I had never read "Cantor cube" anyway.

Comment: What if you take a subset of $2^\omega$, meeting each $B_s$ in a subset of cardinal $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @YCor It seems that base zero-dimemsional sets are related to strong measure zero sets, so situtation becames to be interesting.

Comment: I think the name of the tag is a mistake. People working in the area call cardinals like the ones you investigate cardinal characteristics. The name involves a field, techniques and a body of related results. Talk of "small uncountable cardinals" doesn't do that (seems like noise to me).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Uff. We have discussed this question on meta and it seemed to me that all participating in discussion agreed that introducing this tag was a good idea...

Comment: No, I objected to it and the answer supporting the idea is downvoted.

Comment: To clarify: I think that a tag for "cardinal characteristics" would be useful, and would cover all the questions for which you propose the other tag.

Comment: @YCor and Taras Banakh - I have posted a few comment about the newly created tag [in MO editor's lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2019/3/16). This is related more to the question whether we should have waited longer before creating the tag and I did this also in the hope that this helps to get some feedback from the moderators. But since you were involved in the discussion on meta, I thought it might be reasonable to let you know.

Comment: As usual, there are very few participants to the tag discussion on meta https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4154/ and this is a pity. I basically agree with @AndrésE.Caicedo with the intended scope of the tag, but I think that [tag:small-uncountable-cardinal] can encompass this. Also I made explicit objection to Andrés' tag suggestion, not about the scope, but notably about how it's likely to be misused, but this has been ignored. Taras, it would be useful that you give (on the meta discussion) your opinion about the various aspects of the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

After an e-mail communication with Lubomyr Zdomskyy, we came to the conclusion that the base zero-dimensionality is equivalent to the [Rothberger property.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothberger_space)

So, $\mathfrak z=\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$ by a [result of Fremlin and Miller](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/hmr.pdf).